# Do I need one N3904 for each LED?

Tags: led, transistor, arduino-duemilanove

I want to control 4 (or more) LEDs using the PWM output pins of my Arduino.

Here is how I have it on a breadboard, and it's working for me.

**Question:**
Is this schematic inefficient? Are there any issues with this design?

[image]

Comment: How powerful are your LEDs?

Comment: It'll be more efficient if you'd just connect anode to the PWM output and cathode to the ground through resistor. Now there will be more current through the base to the ground than through LED

Comment: I will be using pink, blue, green, and yellow LED's.

I need to control each LED independently, and change voltage dynamically (fade on / off  or blink etc.. )


Hopefully that helps some.

Comment: @ThomasWeller sorry, do you mean using the PWM output pins to supply power to each LED?  If I turn on multiple LED's at the same time, would they receive enough power?  I guess I'm not sure if there is a voltage difference when using analogWrite(n, 255) across multiple pins at the same time.

Comment: @KIIV oh wow, I think you're referring to something like the schematic in the answer for this question: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/34989/controlling-common-anode-rgb-led-with-pwm-can-individual-colors-be-done-w-o-tr?rq=1

That is really neat and may be a much simpler circuit design. Thanks

Comment: @user3228313 Just keep that resistor for each LED. Without it, you might be operating on the maximum IO port currents and it may fail eventually

Comment: in general, MOSFETs are a better way to go than BJTs for switching on/off (incl PWM) and they are more efficient energy-wise, not dropping a junction of voltage to be multiplied by the load...

Comment: In the schematic you don’t have any resistors between the PWM pin an the base of the transistor. You really need to add those. Also the resistors for the leds are typically placed on the other side of the transistor (connected directly to the leds).